# Why are preload link not working for JSON requests ?

Tags: javascript, json, html, w3c

The JavaScript on my website loads several JSON to initialize itself.

I would like to preload them so, when the JavaScript will launch an Ajax request on it, they will be loaded instantaneously.

A new [`link`](https://w3c.github.io/preload/) tag exists for that.

I tried to use it to load a JSON like that :

```
<link rel="preload" href="/test.json">
```

However, Chrome seems to load it twice and present a warning in the console :

*The resources test.json was preloaded using link preload but not used within a few seconds from the window's load event. Please make sure it wasn't preloaded for nothing.*

So it seems that preload doesn’t work for JSON.
Indeed, I haven’t found reference to JSON in [the specification](https://w3c.github.io/preload/#link-element-interface-extensions).

Is that correct or am I doing it wrong ?

Comment: JSON is not in the spec. Have you tried something like this: `<link rel="preload" href="test.json" as="json" type="application/json" crossorigin>`

Comment: Also, note that this will only work in Chrome, no other browsers support "preload"

Comment: I tried `<link rel="preload" href="test.json" as="json">` which resulted in an error message complaining bad "as" value.
And yes, I know "preload" is only working for Chrome for now but I’m also using "prefetch" for other browser which is the same problem.

Comment: Okay ... I would also try with `as="script"`

Comment: `as="script"` doesn’t trigger an error but Chrome seems to reload the resource.

Comment: So how about embedd your JSON into a script file, which loads using "preload", and simply access that object

Comment: See also https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=655698#c11

Comment: That one too is interesting : https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=675280&q=preload%20json&colspec=ID%20Pri%20M%20Stars%20ReleaseBlock%20Component%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20OS%20Modified

Answer (score 24):

According to https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Preloading_content , you have to add `as="fetch"` for JSON files.
So your code becomes

`<link rel="preload" href="/test.json" as="fetch">`

It's supported by all modern browsers and you get a warning message if this resource is not used within a few seconds because it is counterproductive to "preload" it in a such case (delay, double load etc.)

It's different from `<link rel="prefetch" ...>` which is to anticipate future navigation and not supported widely.

A Chrome illustrated article about this: https://medium.com/reloading/preload-prefetch-and-priorities-in-chrome-776165961bbf

Answer (score 11):

If you have the same problem as me, your response is probably being sent with `Vary: Accept`, the preload request is sent with `Accept: */*`, and the fetch/xhr request is being made with `Accept: application/json`.

It seems like the preload `Accept:` behavior can't be changed (sigh), so you'll have to either remove the `Vary: Accept`, or make the fetch/xhr request with a matching `Accept:` header.

Comment: I tried to set `Vary: */*` on the ajax call while loading the json but Chrome gives me the same warning as before : « The resource ... was preloaded using link preload but not used within a few seconds from the window's load event. Please make sure it wasn't preloaded for nothing. »

Comment: I reported an issue here: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=962642

Comment: I ran into the same problem. In my case the JS library I was using for XHR (plotly, which itself was using an old version of d3) was adding extra `Accept` headers. Removing the `setRequestHeader` call from the request fixed it for me.

Answer (score 8):

You have to add not only as="fetch", but ([based on this comment](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=850099#c5)) also crossorigin="anonymous". This should work:

`<link rel="preload" href="/test.json" as="fetch" crossorigin="anonymous">`

Answer (score 3):

Turns out there has been a bug in Chrome for using the `fetch` API combined with `rel=preload` [here](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=652228). I solved this by using `XMLHttpRequest` instead.

Even though it seems to have been fixed in Chrome 62 it seems like I could still reproduce this on my Chrome 63.

Comment: it is indeed still an issue.

Comment: i added an issue here, we'll see what they say https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=850099

Comment: There is a [workaround](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59628026/3075942) for `fetch`, found thanks to the bug report by @Prisoner

Comment: Odd I’m still having a problem with XHR. Still not sure what I’m going wrong.

Answer (score 2):

Here is the approach that works both in Chrome and Safari.

```
<link rel="preload" as="fetch" href="/data.json">
```

```
fetch('/data.json', {
    method: 'GET',
    credentials: 'include',
    mode: 'no-cors',
})
```

This answer contains more details and explanation why and how does it work https://stackoverflow.com/a/63814972/1387163

Answer (score 0):

I tried so many variations on the allowed values on https://w3c.github.io/preload/#as-attribute but the only thing that worked for me to fetch JSON data properly was removing the `type` and `as` directives completely and relying on the browser to figure it out. Works in the latest Chrome but I guess it might change as browser behaviour changes.

[image: Developer tools image showing XHR push]

Answer (score 0):

According to the Chrome [bug](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=675280) mentioned in the comments, `preload` doesn't work when you have `responseType = 'blob'`.

The workaround is to set `responseType = 'arraybuffer'` and then in `onload` convert to blob manually using `var blob = new Blob([xhr.response], {type: xhr.getResponseHeader("Content-Type")});`

Answer (score -3):

Try `as="xhr"`. Seems to be working for me in Chrome when I do a server push - that's not exactly the same as the HTML tag but if you are getting that resources via Ajax / XmlHttpRequest, this might fix it.

Comment: Using as="xhr" gives a warning in console : <link rel=preload> must have a valid `as` value

Answer (score -5):

Try `as="object"`. Seems to work for me:

```
<link rel="preload" href="/test.json" as="object">
```