# Preload JSON file with <link rel="preload">

Tags: json, preload

I'm using Angular 5 application and i'm loading quite big JSON file. The problem is that it takes a long time to load main `.js` bundle, initialize it, bootstrap Angular app which later fetches that JSON file.
If i could preload that JSON file while Angular app gets ready, it would speed up initial page load.

I tried to use `<link rel="preload" href="/path/to/json" as="script">` but that doesn't help and now JSON file is loaded twice. I tried other `as` values but nothing works.

What should be correct way to preload JSON file?

Comment: See [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41655955/why-are-preload-link-not-working-for-json-requests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41655955/why-are-preload-link-not-working-for-json-requests)

Answer (score 10):

You can use `<link rel="preload" href="/path/to/json" as="fetch">` .

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Preloading_content#What_types_of_content_can_be_preloaded