# Is it possible to preload binary file in html <link rel="preload">?

Tags: javascript, html, http, fetch-api

I have a binary file that I load using fetch is there a way to preload that file with `<link rel="preload">`?

**NOTE**: There is this question [Preload JSON file with](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50122109/387194)  and the answer solve the problem for me.
I'm adding this so it's easier to find this in Google.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `as="fetch"` to preload any content loaded in JavaScript including binary:

```html
<link rel="preload" href="/path/to/binary/file" as="fetch">
```