# How to properly prefetch a json endpoint in Chrome?

Tags: javascript, html, preload

I am trying to speed up the network critical path on a website, and find out about the great `<link rel=preload`. So I try to anticipate the call that my single page application do as soon as the JS kicks in, I have put in my index.html

```
<link rel="preload" href="/api/searchItems" as="fetch" />
```

Then as the JS starts I make the same call with the help of the `axios` library:

```
await axios.get(`/api/searchItems`, { params: queryParams });
```

I would expect to see the call of Axios returning instantly the preloaded JSON file but instead, I see this:

[image]

As you can see the same call is loaded twice.
What I am doing wrong?

EDIT: I have added `cache-control: public` and nothing changes.
EDIT2: I also tried this code instead of axios:

```
  let data = await fetch('/api/searchItems')
    .then(response => {
      if (response.ok) {
        return response.json();
      }
      throw new Error('HTTP error ' + response.status);
    })
    .catch(() => {
      data = null; // Just clear it and if it errors again when
      // you make the call later, handle it then
    });
```

And nothing change

Comment: Your response appears to have headers saying it can't be cached, not even briefly. You'll want to remove those.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder thanks for the reply. But the response of my webserver is: `cache-control: no-cache`, private. So I would expect it can be cached

Comment: *Something* is telling the browser not to cache it, even if not that specific header. Otherwise, it would be cached.

Comment: Note that `no-cache` [requires revalidation with the server](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Cache-Control#Cacheability). I'm not a caching expert, but that may be responsible for what you're seeing. *Edit:* You said in a comment elsewhere that you've tried `public` and it still didn't work, so that alone would seem not to be the problem.

Comment: Running into the same issue. I found this interesting. Not sure if it's something we can get axios to pass in as well, https://stackoverflow.com/a/59628026

Answer (score 0):

Three options for you:

1. It looks like your response has headers making it uncacheable for some reason. You may be able to fix it so it's cacheable.
2. Use a [service worker](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ServiceWorker).
3. Another approach, if this is really critical path, is to have some inline JavaScript that actually does the call and modify the code that will do the call later to look to see if the previous result is available, like this:

   ```
   let firstLoad = fetch("/api/searchItems")
       .then(response => {
           if (response.ok) {
               return response.json();
           }
           throw new Error("HTTP error " + response.status);
       })
       .catch(() => {
           firstLoad = null; // Just clear it and if it errors again when 
                             // you make the call later, handle it then
       });
   ```

   *(I'm using `fetch` there because you may want to do it before you've loaded `axios`.)*

   Then in the code that wants this data:

   ```
   (firstLoad || axios.get("/api/searchItems").then(response => response.data))
   .then(/*...*/)
   .catch(/*...*/);
   firstLoad = null;
   ```

If the content requires revalidation (and you're using `no-cache`, so it does¹), #2 and #3 have the advantage of not requiring a second request to the server.

---

¹ From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Cache-Control#Cacheability):

> `no-cache`
>
> The response may be stored by any cache, even if the response is normally non-cacheable. **However, the stored response MUST always go through validation with the origin server first before using it**...

*(my emphasis)*

Comment: I have set `cache-control: public` on the response, and it happens the same

Comment: @ciaoben - Smart thing to try. (Did you double-check with the Network tab that that change did go through the stack correctly?) As I say, though, *something* is making that response non-cacheable. Axios? Is the way you're doing the request bypassing cache? In any case, #2 and #3 should bypass the problem (but IMHO you're right to keep looking for the answer to *why*)...

Comment: Thanks. I quicky tried replacing axios with fetch, same happens... damn. I also checked browser settings and it is all normal.. I edited the question

Comment: Is it possible that no-cache is sent just because the web inspector is open (it's a setting you can disable).

Comment: @ciaoben - See Jamund's point above. If you have devtools open, there's often a setting to disable cache there. In Chrome's devtools the default is off, but you might check to see if you've turned it on (it persists).

Comment: @T.J.Crowder yes thank you, but the option is already checked :/

Comment: @ciaoben - If it's *checked*, that means it *disables* cache (at least, that's how it works on Chrome [and related] and Firefox).

Comment: @T.J.Crowder no sorry, it is un-checked. My bad sorry!