# Does Safari support Link rel=preload headers for XMLHttpRequest?

Tags: javascript, safari, xmlhttprequest, http-headers, preload

I'm trying to optimise the speed of some web page that loads some JSON data using `XMLHttpRequest` from the same origin. I have added the `Link` HTTP header to the response of the web page, like this:

```
Link: </api/endpoint>; rel=preload; as=fetch; crossorigin
```

This works fine in Chrome. I see that the API endpoint is requested once (due to the preload instruction), and then used for the `XMLHttpRequest`.

However, in Safari it does not work. I see that the API endpoint is requested twice (once due to the preload instruction, and once more for the `XMLHttpRequest`). Also, a warning shows up in the console:

> [Warning] The resource https://my-origin.com/api/endpoint was preloaded using link preload but not used within a few seconds from the window's load event. Please make sure it wasn't preloaded for nothing.

I have tried several variants of the `Link` headers (without `crossorigin` and with `crossorigin=use-credentials`). I also tried setting `withCredentials=true` on the XHR object. None of those combinations gave a different result.

I read some other [question/answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63814972/251760), where it was explained that preloading fetch requests is possible by using `mode: "no-cors"`. However, it is not possible to set that mode for `XMLHttpRequest`.

Is it possible to preload `XMLHttpRequest`s (from the same origin) in Safari?