# HTML preload link not not working to load fetch

Tags: javascript, html, fetch-api, preload

I am preloading an html page using the link tag

```html
<link rel="preload" href="/pages/test" as="fetch">
```

And then fetching it later using `fetch`

```js
async function loadPage() {
  const html = await (await fetch("/pages/test")).text();
}
loadPage();
```

But two seperate requests are still being made. I have already tried the solutions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41655955), but none of them worked for me.

Comment: The fetch request *is sent* but is intercepted by the browser before it hits the server and the response served from the browser cache. This will appear as two network calls, but your server should only see one request.

Comment: @DanPantry I am using chrome (and I tested preloading an image, which did work), so preloading is supported. And I put a console.log on the server (I'm using node.js) that logged the url of every request, and "http://127.0.0.1:8080/pages/test" was logged twice

Answer (score 0):

`rel="preload"` should only be used to fetch a JSON or ArrayBuffer response and shouldn't be used to download an HTML page. Also include the `crossorigin` attribute to avoid duplicate requests.